# Hyperledger Fabric Nodejs SDK taking time for getting proposal result (5 seconds approx)

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using `Hyperledger Fabric` framework with SDK written in `node.js`.

The network consists of:

- 3 Peers
- 2 Orderer (Kafka Type)
- 4 Kafka
- 3 Zookeepers
- 1 CA-Server
- 1 Couchdb

And they all are on separate machines. 
The issue is I am getting query response very late as you can see from screenshot attached

[image]

It takes approximately 5 seconds to return a response (It is just read operation. There is nothing to write in the function I am using).

The same function If I query from peer using:

```
peer chaincode query  -C assetchain -n assetchaincode -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["1wdc6enjhq1z3gc"], "Function":"getUser"}'
```

returns the response immediately.

I have done debugging on nodejs sdk and found that the function `channel.sendTransactionProposal(request);` returns a promise and takes almost 5 seconds (happening in my case and shown in postman.).

Please let me know why it is happening.

Any answer/comment would be really appreciated.

**Update:** I tried again by stopping all the peers, orderers and cleared the `/var/hyperledger/production` dir, deleted `kafka` and `zookeeper` logs and the performance is good now. I am getting response in 60-70 ms. Does anyone know what was the issue?

Comment: @DeputInfotech did you get any solution for this issue other than restarting the peers and orderer, because I'm also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If you just perform a query, you should try `Channel.queryByChaincode`

Comment: It takes 5 seconds even If I do not use nodejs sdk and directly query the peer0

Comment: Whereas, If I query peer1 it provide immediate response